# Updating multiple wso2 apimanger gateways

Tags: wso2

I have configured 2 wso2 api gateways (say gw1 and gw2) behind a load balancer (say lb1) . I have configured publisher in another node( say pub1). In pub1 box /etc/hosts file I have api gateway url to that of lb1. Now whenever I update or add a new api on pub1 it does not get immediately reflected on both gw1 and gw2, it gets reflected on one of the two. Is there a way programtically force api manager to refresh the list of published api's?

Answer (score 1):

You need us deployment synchronizer to sync the artifacts across the gateway nodes. In your scenario, one gateway will need to be treated as the manager whilst the other one as the worker node.

Pls refer the documentation [here](http://docs.wso2.org/display/Cluster/Configuring+Deployment+Synchronizer) on how to configure deployment synchronizer.